# Hooks - the type or namespace HookType could not be found

Tags: c#, api, winapi, hook

I am trying to learn about hooks in the Win32 API with C#. What I am trying to actually do is how to call a command when there is a low-level user activity like a mouse-move or a keystroke. I am currently reading this article: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188966.aspx

However, when I put the following code from the example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;

class Win32Hooks
{
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(HookType code,
    CbtHook.CbtProc func,
    IntPtr hInstance,
    int threadID);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhook);
static void Main()
{

}
}
```

However, I am receiving an error that the type or the namespace 'HookType' could not be found. Any idea how to fix this? Also it would be great if someone could recommend an article on Win32 API Hooks with C# for a beginner. I have been searching hard but the clearest I came up to was this one pasted above.

Comment: See here http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/HookType.html

Comment: I would suggest that a beginner not learn the Win32 API, with or without C#.

Comment: Sorry I thought the article is structured in step by step my mistake. John Saunders I am not a complete C# beginner, I have knowledge of several languages. What I meant was that I am beginner in the Windows API functions and classes.

Answer (score 3):

The HookType is defined in the article you reference.

```
    public enum HookType : int
    {
       WH_JOURNALRECORD = 0,
       WH_JOURNALPLAYBACK = 1,
       WH_KEYBOARD = 2,
       WH_GETMESSAGE = 3,
       WH_CALLWNDPROC = 4,
       WH_CBT = 5,
       WH_SYSMSGFILTER = 6,
       WH_MOUSE = 7,
       WH_HARDWARE = 8,
       WH_DEBUG = 9,
       WH_SHELL = 10,
       WH_FOREGROUNDIDLE = 11,
       WH_CALLWNDPROCRET = 12,        
       WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13,
       WH_MOUSE_LL = 14
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't see it, thought things in the article are in another kind of structure . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined the `HookType` type (message is very much self-explanatory isn't it?)

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setwindowshookex